# Is BetterTouchTool the recommended app to improve gestures?

Tags: multi-touch

I was looking for a way to add more "gestures" for my mbp (to accesss spaces for example) and I read about BetterTouchTool which seems to work quite well.

I was just wondering if there's any other tool like that one, and if another is more recommended.

Comment: Nothing else compares.  It's even better now than it was in 2011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally use it, and believe me it's awesome. I'll give it 4.5/5

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is another application out there called [JiTouch](http://www.jitouch.com/). It is much better than BetterTouchTool (except for the window snapping, which it doesn't have). I would recommend JiTouch over BetterTouchTool, even though JiTouch is a $6 paid application.

[image: JiTouch Features]
[image: JiTouch Pref pane]

Answer (score 0):

called JiTouch. It is much better than BetterTouchTool (except for the window snapping, which it doesn't have). I would recommend JiTouch over BetterTouchTool, even though JiTouch is a $6 paid application.